# htaccess redirect 301 https www to non www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, web, https

Currently only the homepage is redirecting from www.example.com and example.com to `https://example.com`

I try to redirect:

```
1. http://www.example.com/otherpages to https://example.com/otherpages 
2. http://example.com/otherpages to https://example.com/otherpages
3. https://www.example.com to https://example.com
3. https://www.example.com/otherpages to https://example.com/otherpages
```

Tried to use some former questions but can't figure it out.

current state in .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my\-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all that code for the conditions you want. Replace your all of that code with this and change to your domain.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I am using wordpress and from top to `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` was written by wordpress itself. Do you think

Comment: It will harm wordpress If I will remove the code? (I think so..) Thanks for your help

Comment: @hagaishaul No it won't. I know what I'm doing or I wouldn't have answered the question. The wordpress code is still there,  at the bottom. You asked for help and I provided a solution.

Comment: Thanks it is working ofcourse, and sorry for the previous comment

Comment: @hagaishaul no problem can you accept the answer please?